# update many rows in Table A with few rows from Table B using merge on stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, cross-join, merge-statement

I have data on Table 1 like this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ehVg.png)

> IdT1 ,    IdT1Group
>
> 11    ,   30
>
> 12    ,   30
>
> 13    ,   30

And On Table 2 Like: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juCDq.png)

> IdT2, IdT1,   Detail, Synchronise
>
> 1 ,   11  ,   A   ,   inserted
>
> 2 ,   11  ,   B   ,   inserted
>
> 3 ,   12  ,   A   ,   inserted
>
> 4 ,   12  ,   C   ,   inserted

I have tblSource like this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgDU2.png)

> IdT2, IdT1,   Detail
>
> 1 ,   11  ,   A
>
> 2 ,   11  ,   B
>
> 5 ,   11  ,   C

I got the tblSource from :

```
Select Top 1 From Tbl2 where IdT1Group = 30
```

And I hope I can Update Tbl2 to become : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxfgC.png)

```
IdT2,   IdT1,   Detail, Synchronise

1       11        A     updated

2       11        B     updated

5       11        C     inserted

3       12        A     updated

4       12        B     updated

6       12        C     inserted

7       13        A     inserted

8       13        B     inserted

9       13        C     inserted
```

This is code that I use to get what I expect:

```
    Declare @IdT1Group integer = 30
;WITH tblTbl2
    AS (SELECT table2.* FROM table2 INNER JOIN table1 ON table2.IdT1 = table1.IdT1 AND IdT1Group = @IdT1Group)
    MERGE INTO tblTbl2 AS tblTarget
    USING (SELECT tblT2.*, table1.IdT1 AS T1Id FROM tbl2 AS tblT2 CROSS JOIN table1 where IdT1Group = @IdT1Group)
            AS tblSource ON tblTarget.IdT1 = tblSource.T1Id And tblTarget.IdT2 = tblSource.IdT2
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE 
        SET     Detail = tblSource.Detail, Synchronise = 'updated'
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
        DELETE
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN            
        INSERT (IdT1, Detail, Synchronise)
        VALUES (tblSource.T1Id, tblSource.Detail, 'inserted');
```

But This is what i got : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNjkV.png)

```
IdT2    IdT1    Detail  Synchronise
1       11        A     updated
2       11        B     updated
5       11        C     inserted
6       12        A     inserted
7       12        B     inserted
8       12        C     inserted
9       13        A     inserted
10      13        B     inserted
11      13        C     inserted
```

This Code for me to do some trial:

```
drop table if exists table1
create table table1(idt1 int, idt1group int)

insert into table1 values (11,30),(12,30),(13,30)

drop table if exists table2

create table table2 (idt2 int, idt1 int, detail varchar(2), Synchronise varchar(15))

insert into table2 values (1,11,'A', 'Inserted'),(2,11,'B', 'Inserted'),
(3,12,'A', 'Inserted'),
(4,12,'B', 'Inserted')

drop table if exists tbl2

create table tbl2 (idt2 int, idt1 int, detail varchar(2), Synchronise varchar(15))
insert into tbl2 values (1, 11,'A', 'Inserted'), 
(2,11,'B', 'Inserted'), (5,11,'C', 'Inserted')

Declare @IdT1Group integer = 30

SELECT table1.IdT1 AS T1Id, tblT2.* FROM tbl2 AS tblT2 CROSS JOIN table1 where IdT1Group = @IdT1Group

;WITH tblTbl2
    AS (SELECT table2.* FROM table2 INNER JOIN table1 ON table2.IdT1 = table1.IdT1 AND IdT1Group = @IdT1Group)
    MERGE INTO tblTbl2 AS tblTarget
    USING (SELECT tblT2.*, table1.IdT1 AS T1Id FROM tbl2 AS tblT2 CROSS JOIN table1 where IdT1Group = @IdT1Group)
            AS tblSource ON tblTarget.IdT1 = tblSource.T1Id And tblTarget.IdT2 = tblSource.IdT2
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE 
        SET     Detail = tblSource.Detail, Synchronise = 'updated'
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
        DELETE
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN            
        INSERT (IdT1, Detail, Synchronise)
        VALUES (tblSource.T1Id, tblSource.Detail, 'inserted');

select * From Table2
```

Comment: Please don't supply data as an image, supply it as `text`. i'm afraid, however, that that data doesn't make sense for what you're saying is in SQL Server. A value can't extended over multiple rows in SQL Server, each row has it's own value. Please take the time to remove the images and provide us with `text` versions of your data, or even better as DDL and DML statements. Also include the logic behind what you're trying to achieve; explain your goal. It is very difficult for us to help you here, as we only have images, data that isn't valid, and a query that doesn't work. Thanks.

Comment: okay thank you for the suggestion, its because I changed the actual data to an imagery

Answer (score 0):

You are deleting give data

```
3       12        A     updated

4       12        B     updated
```

ANd this data does not exists in

```
Declare @IdT1Group integer = 30

SELECT table1.IdT1 AS T1Id, tblT2.* FROM tbl2 AS tblT2 CROSS JOIN table1 where IdT1Group = @IdT1Group
```

So it's delete data if you still want to update this then you have to check if data not exists in then update it.

```
Declare @IdT1Group integer = 30

SELECT table1.IdT1 AS T1Id, tblT2.* FROM tbl2 AS tblT2 CROSS JOIN table1 where IdT1Group = @IdT1Group


MERGE table2 AS tblTarget
--traget table 
USING 


--data src
(SELECT table1.IdT1 AS T1Id, tblT2.* FROM tbl2 AS tblT2 CROSS JOIN table1 where IdT1Group = @IdT1Group)
AS tblSource ON tblTarget.IdT1 = tblSource.T1Id And tblTarget.IdT2 = tblSource.IdT2
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE 
SET     Detail = tblSource.Detail, Synchronise = 'updated'

--Delete QUery
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
DELETE

--insert query
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN            
INSERT ([idt2],IdT1, Detail, Synchronise)
VALUES (tblSource.idt2,tblSource.T1Id, tblSource.Detail, 'inserted');

select * From Table2
```

let me know if you still have question

Comment: Can you help me to get what I hope to be? ==> https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxfgC.png

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
--data query

drop table  table1
create table table1(idt1 int, idt1group int)

insert into table1 values (11,30),(12,30),(13,30)

drop table  table2

create table table2 (idt2 int, idt1 int, detail varchar(2), Synchronise varchar(15))

insert into table2 values (1,11,'A', 'Inserted'),(2,11,'B', 'Inserted'),
(3,12,'A', 'Inserted'),
(4,12,'B', 'Inserted')

drop table  tbl2

create table tbl2 (idt2 int, idt1 int, detail varchar(2), Synchronise varchar(15))
insert into tbl2 values (1, 11,'A', 'Inserted'), 
(2,11,'B', 'Inserted'), (5,11,'C', 'Inserted')


--main query

Declare @IdT1Group integer = 30

SELECT table1.IdT1 AS T1Id, tblT2.* FROM tbl2 AS tblT2 CROSS JOIN table1 where IdT1Group = @IdT1Group

MERGE table2 AS tblTarget
--traget table 
USING 


--data src
(SELECT table1.IdT1 AS T1Id, tblT2.* FROM tbl2 AS tblT2 CROSS JOIN table1 where IdT1Group = @IdT1Group)
AS tblSource ON tblTarget.IdT1 = tblSource.T1Id And tblTarget.IdT2 = tblSource.IdT2
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN 
UPDATE 
SET   Synchronise = 'updated';



MERGE table2 AS tblTarget
--traget table 
USING 


--data src
(SELECT table1.IdT1 AS T1Id, tblT2.* FROM tbl2 AS tblT2 CROSS JOIN table1 where IdT1Group = @IdT1Group)
AS tblSource ON tblTarget.IdT1 = tblSource.T1Id And tblTarget.IdT2 = tblSource.IdT2
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE 
SET     Detail = tblSource.Detail, Synchronise = 'updated'

--insert query
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN            
INSERT ([idt2],IdT1, Detail, Synchronise)
VALUES (tblSource.idt2,tblSource.T1Id, tblSource.Detail, 'inserted');

select * From Table2
```

Comment: Sorry I tried it on my Sql Servers and it comes an error: _Msg 8672, Level 16, State 1, Line 38
The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once. This happens when a target row matches more than one source row. A MERGE statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the target table multiple times. Refine the ON clause to ensure a target row matches at most one source row, or use the GROUP BY clause to group the source rows._

Comment: You have duplicates recorded plz truncate and see